# How to avoid duplicate entry when display records using linq skip and take

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, linq-to-sql

Its simple `Retrieve Post` method code.
I'm sorting records and based on pagesize(count of records) `Skip and Take next records`.

```
 public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetPost(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, int? page = 0, int? pageSize = null, params SortExpression<TEntity>[] sortExpressions)
    {
        //Filter the query set
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = DbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
            if (query.Count() < 1)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
        // sort the filtered query result
        if (sortExpressions != null)
        {
            IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> orderedQuery = null;
            for (var i = 0; i < sortExpressions.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    if (sortExpressions[i].SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                    {
                        orderedQuery = query.OrderBy(sortExpressions[i].SortBy);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        orderedQuery = query.OrderByDescending(sortExpressions[i].SortBy);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (sortExpressions[i].SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                    {
                        orderedQuery = orderedQuery.ThenBy(sortExpressions[i].SortBy);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        orderedQuery = orderedQuery.ThenByDescending(sortExpressions[i].SortBy);
                    }

                }
            }
            // skip rows according to page number and page size
            if (page != null)
            {
                query = orderedQuery.Skip(((int)page - 1) * (int)pageSize);
            }
        }

        if (pageSize != null)
        {
            query = query.Take((int)pageSize);
        }

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Issue is I'm displaying records into mobile application in `DESC` order so that most recent post come first.

for example -
Record set is

```
1
2
3
```

`pagesize is =2` (means one page can display only 2 records when I do scroll it will hit again `GetPost` method to skip previous 2 records and fetch next 2 latest records)

now display records in desc order -

```
3
2
1
```

Now if new 4th record added and again we scroll now this time pagesize =2 again,
now it will duplicate post 3 again bcoz previously it is there on mobile screen only and newly added 4 will be appended with that 3 like below-

final output -

```
4
3
3
2
1
```

> I want to avoid such scenario.
>
> one solution is can check for repeated posts on mobile application side , is there any good way to handle at api side in method GetPost?
>
> is there any better and good way to maintain/avoid such scenario?
>   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Your GetPost method should take the last post Id as parameter.

When you load all posts, which are not displayed yet with .AddRange() method.

And only after you have all the posts, they could be fragmented to pages based on page size.

Comment: any sample example for addrange in paging?

Comment: Maybe something like this - `for (var page = 1; page <= Math.ceil(items / itemsOnPage); page++) {
           //page = current page
    }`